# Touchpad suddenly broken on 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: xorg, touchpad, synaptics, xserver, libinput

I turned on my Aspire One last night and the touchpad was totally non-responsive. To use my laptop, I needed to get a mouse. The touchpad has worked fine for me for more than a year now. I am using Lubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. With the mouse, I was able to use my computer, and write this.

In trying to troubleshoot, I did what others have advised. I ran:

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
```

I got back the following:

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=06cb Product=74a3 Version=0100
N: Name="Synaptics TM2985-009"
P: Phys=i2c-SYN1B82:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/808622C1:00/i2c-0/i2c-SYN1B82:00/0018:06CB:74A3.0001/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=6f3800001000003
```

I also ran `$ xinput list` and got back:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM2985-009                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

I am new at this. From what I can tell, reading online, this indicates that the problem is most likely not with the kernal; perhaps the issue is either with **xserver-xorg-input-libinput** or **xserver-xorg-input-synaptics.**  I checked, and both are installed on my machine. I also looked up the publishing history for those two; they appear to have been changed on 2019-10-18. That confused me because my touchpad broke only recently. I'm not sure what to do next. I'd like to get this working again.

Comment: For now, use an external mouse or the previous kernel (4.15.0-70) as suggested in [comment #7](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798/comments/7) or read the [full bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798).

Answer (score 0):

This is most common problem appear when installing updates or installing new linux distribution. And it is due to "linux-kernel-generic" this package, and in this package there are many installed kernel drivers and the latest one which makes crush in my laptop "linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-72-generic".So the only thing you have to do is installing previous versions of this driver.

To remove;

> &sudo apt remove linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-72-generic

then the previous version worked for me is; "linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1007-oracle"

to install it;

> $sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1007-oracle

**WARNING; Removing the package and not replacing it results the network not working.**